# Non-static method Maatwebsite\Excel\Readers\LaravelExcelReader::all() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Tags: laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm getting this error whenever trying to upload and excel file

My function is

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Excel;

function:-

public function importProduct(){ 
$file = Input::file('file');
$file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move('excelData/',$file_name);
$result = \Excel::load('excelData/'.$file_name, function($reader){
$reader::all();
})->get();
return json_encode($result);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = \Excel::load('excelData/'.$file_name, function(LaravelExcelReader $reader){
$reader::all();
})->get();
```

I think this should work, if you are using 2.1 version of excel

Answer (score 0):

Two Steps

1.First get the Path

```
$path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
```

2. Get data in array

```
$data = Excel::load($path)->get();
```

Now we can Play with data array